# GWT mvp : Places , RequestFactory and SmartGwt and gwt-sl

Tags: smartgwt, gwt-mvp, requestfactory

I am new to GWT and MVP and have explored a few libraries (gwt-sl, gwt-presenter,gwt-dispatch) and frameworks (smartgwt ..) and i am getting very confused.
I have decided to stick with using smartgwt ui components and gwt mvp to handle them. smartgwt is modelled on using a datasource which i would like to ideally extend (and populate using dto's (or proxy objects using gwt's request factory ) ) . however i have not got the hang of all these right now.

a) In the gwt mvp that google has layed out what exactly is the state of a place ? do we always send a person to a new place ? If not and the history maintains the place token then how is the state loaded ?

b) from another post about [gwt mvp where is the model ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510571/gwt-mvp-with-places-activities-wheres-the-model) most of us tuned to typical mvc design paradigms would suppose that the model state is present within the presenter. i suppose then as suggested [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105579/gwt-mvp-with-activities-and-places-global-references) the clientfactory would be the appropriate place to have the current model being displayed in the view stored ?

c) i would like to know if it is possible to attempt to use requestfactory to populate smartgwt databounded components ? ( from what i understand using the smartgwt server side framework does essentially the same thing .. transmitting only changes in the object graph across the wire ?)

d) [On page 47 of David chandler's slide](http://www.slideshare.net/turbomanage/whats-new-in-gwt-22) i dont quite understand the layout that is being proposed. ( 2 placeChangeHandler's  ? 2 sets of widgetList's for each of the activity manager's ? Can someone kindly explain that ?

e) can anyone share their experience with [gwt-sl](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-sl/) (for server side spring integration ?)

thanks in advance to all the gwt gurus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with the SmartGWT QuickStart Guide.  We strongly recommend against using MVP with SmartGWT, as SmartGWT already has a built-in data binding paradigm which we believe provides more features with far less code.

So, learn the SmartGWT data binding approach in depth, look through the samples, try using it, then return to the confusing materials you have been reviewing and ask yourself the question: do they simplify anything?  Do they make it easier to add a feature I need?  If not, don't bother with them.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am actually looking into the data binding approach. The problem with the quick start guide is that it quickly references to a lot of classes with concepts which is great to understand parts of the holistic picture but sometimes does not help from the perspective "that you do not know what more you would need to know" before you dig in to the code. I like smartgwt but somehow i just havnt, yet, got it to groove to my liking even with the showcase examples. That being said i would want to know about handling view transition in smartgwt which is y i was looking at gwt mvp

Comment: That feeling ("do not know what more you need to know") is not shared by most readers of the QuickStart Guide based on feedback we've received, and probably comes from looking at other, inapplicable architectures and trying to understand how they fit (they don't!).  There is nothing special to do for "view transition" - show and hide components to show and hide different views, or if your top level view is a TabSet, call selectTab().